Stripe Subscription Invoices always have a zero value Stripe fee
I'm attempting to capture the Stripe Fees per Subscription Invoice using Stripe Billing using the api. I've retreieved what I beleieve should be the right field using the following:
const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.retrieve(
  'pi_123456',
  {
    expand: ['latest_charge.balance_transaction'],
  }
);

const feeDetails = paymentIntent.latest_charge.balance_transaction.fee;`

The value is always returned at 0 however if I view the Balances menu and filter the list by 'Stripe fee' there is multiple fees listed but all with a description of 'Billing - Usage Fee (2024-09-08)'.
Is it possible that the fees are somehow being consolidated or am I looking in the completely wrong place to capture the individual Subscription Invoice fee.
I'm not all that familiar with Stripe and I'd appreciate any support, thanks.

questions about how Stripe fees are charged are probably better directed to their support team

The fee in the balance_transaction is the raw card processing fee. There can be other fees for usage of Billing/Invoices but those are taken in bulk and there are reports you can export from the Dashboard to reconcile them, they're not connected directly in the API this way.
